# Why does my budgie applet not display in the budgie-panel?

Tags: python, gtk, applet, budgie

I am writing an applet for Ubuntu Budgie in python.I wrote some code,debugged with no errors, saved it  and put the folder with the files in ~/.local/share/budgie-desktop/plugin directory so I can add it on panel.I tried to add it as an applet but nothing happened.So I am not sure if is running smoothly or not.
The code is in this link

https://gist.github.com/cgiannakidis70/db0cf31558e6c20e95716679b831fd8f

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import gi
import gi.repository
gi.require_version('Budgie', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Budgie, GObject, Gtk, Gio

class myapplet(GObject.GObject, Budgie.Plugin):

    __gtype_name__ = "myapplet"

    def __int__(self):

        GObject.GObject.__init__(self)

    def do_get_panel_widged(self, uuid):

        return myappletApplet(uuid)

class myappletApplet(Budgie.Applet):

    def __init__(self, uuid):

        Budgie.Applet.__init__(self)

        self.button = Gtk.ToggleButton.new("A")
        self.button.set_relief(Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE)
        self.button.set_active(False)
        self.button.set_tooltip_text("Apple Menu")
        self.add(self.button)
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked)
        self.show_all()

    def button_clicked(self):

        dialog = menu(self)
        response = dialog.run()

        dialog.destroy()

        #Create Menu
        menu = Gio.Menu()
        menu.append("About This PC", "app.about_this_pc")
        self.set_applet_menu(menu)

        #create an action for the option "About This PC" of the menu
        about_this_pc_action = Gio.SimpleAction.new("about_this_pc", None)
        about_this_pc_action.connect("activate", self.about_this_pc_cb)
        self.add_action(about_this_pc_action)



    def about_this_pc_cb(self, action, parameter):

        print("About This PC")




Gtk.main()
```

The applet is about a button in panel which every time i push it opens a dropdown menu with some options that can be activated.Like the "user-indicator-applet".

Right now I am stacked and I can not continue the code .Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have rolled back your edits because your question has effectively completely changed from your start point. Remember, please ask new questions e.g. "how do I display a popup menu".  What we don't do is change the question all the time otherwise answers will not make much sense because the question has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I spot a typo!

```
def do_get_panel_widged(self, uuid):
```

It should be:

```
def do_get_panel_widget(self, uuid):
```

What is happening is that the typo version is just defining a function.  Implicitly do_get_panel_widget is being called but it is a stub function so the applet will never appear.

With the correct name - you are now overriding the inbuilt stub function and calling out to your new applet code.

Secondly in your example you are missing a .plugin file - you need this to allow the module to run.  The plugin file is this format:

```
[Plugin]
Loader=python3
Module=test
Name=test
Description=test description
Authors=your name
Copyright=© 2018 email address
Website=https://your-website.com
Icon=we-prefer-symbolic-icons-symbolic
```

Thirdly:

Don't have a Gtk.main() at the end of you main module - that just confuses a Peas based plugin - delete it

Fourth:

Use a Gtk.EventBox() to add your applet in - it is how budgie-desktop 10.4 plugins should now be written - example code below

```
    self.button = Gtk.ToggleButton.new()
    self.button.set_relief(Gtk.ReliefStyle.NONE)
    self.button.set_active(False)
    self.button.set_tooltip_text("Apple Menu")
    box = Gtk.EventBox()
    box.add(self.button)
    self.add(box)
    self.button.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked)
    box.show_all()
    self.show_all()

def button_clicked(self, *args):
```

Fifth:

Notice the button_clicked event is missing an argument - clicked events  in GTK pass the button itself to the signal handler

Lastly - which I havent corrected for you - your clicked function has an uninitialised dialog - and you appear to want to display a Gtk Dialog. Don't!  You will block the main thread of the panel.

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for your reply.About the .plugin file, sorry i did not mention above.I have the .plugin file created and saved in the same folder with the .py file.I corrected the def of the function but I still can not add the applet .

Comment: ok - amended the answer - please review the changes I am suggesting.

Comment: I made the changes you suggest.About the clicked function I replace dialog with menu .Is it ok this?

Comment: @cgiannakisis this is really a new question - what you really want is to display a Gtk.Popover -  or possibly a Gtk.PopoverMenu https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/PopoverMenu.html#Gtk.PopoverMenu.new